# Can you require static functions to be declared in the right order in C#?

Tags: c#, function

In plain C, you need to declare static functions above every function that calls it. In C# this is not required.

Is it possible to enable the C-behaviour in C# too?

Comment: Why do you want such a weird behaviour?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve with this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It forces a structure in the code (where most important functions are usually at the bottom).

Comment: @Muis: maybe your code is too procedural(one file all functions). Try to refactor your class into multiple classes where each represents a logical unit. That'll  increase readability, reusability and maintainability. After that   this question will be pointless. You shouldn't have to care about the order of your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a [custom code analysis rule](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) and then configure the project to run that rule on Build.

However, note that Visual Studio "14" (not yet released at the time of writing) will integrate the [Roslyn compiler platform](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) which will provide a different API for doing code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the list of warnings or add static analysis rules but truth be told - I don't understand why you need this

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/), a Visual Studio plugin that analyzes C# source code to enforce a set of style and consistency rules. You can then have the build fail when one of your constraints fails.